# How to use all array elements as where conditions in LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a string array

```
Dim arrtest = New String() {"First", "Second", "Third"}
```

and a Datatable within a Dataset

```
_dataset.Table.AsEnumerable()
```

how is it possible to select all cases that meet the arrtest elements as where conditions?

The full (by feet) solution would look:

```
dim query = From dt In _dataset.Table.AsEnumerable()
where dt.Field1 = "First" or "Second" or "Third"
```

I thought of using the stringbuilder to generate a string with all the conditions seperated by "or" but was wondering if any of you Linq experts could help me finding a better solution within Linq?

Comment: `arrtest.Contains(dt.Field1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Contains`:

```
dim query = From row In _dataset.Tables(0).AsEnumerable()
            Where arrtest.Contains(row.Field(Of String)("Field1"))
```